# What is the use of 'sep' in paste command of R?

Tags: r, paste

I was working with the paste command in R, when I found that

```
a <- c("something", "to", "paste")  
paste(a, sep="_")
```

produces the output

```
# [1] "something" "to" "paste"
```

Which is same as when I `print` "a"

```
# [1] "something" "to" "paste"
```

So what effect does the `sep` have on the `paste` command in R?

Comment: Try `paste("something", "to", "paste", sep = "_")` (without the `c`)

Comment: Try paste(a[1],a[2],a[3],sep='_').  The problem is you are only passing one item, not three.

Comment: @John, Is that a serious recommendation?

Comment: I'm just trying to illustrate what the problem is, paste(a,sep='_') doesn't paste "a" to anything.  But, I don't do anything serious anymore....

Comment: Maybe you should add what output you were expecting.

Comment: also `help("paste")` can indeed help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sep` is more generally applicable when you have more than two vectors of length greater than 1. If you were looking to get `"something_to_paste"`, then you would be looking for the `collapse` argument.

Try the following to get a sense of what the `sep` argument does:

```
paste(a, 1:3, sep = "_")
# [1] "something_1" "to_2"        "paste_3"
```

and compare it to `collapse`:

```
paste(a, collapse = "_")
# [1] "something_to_paste"
```